# How to pass custom field values into an ajax request in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, metadata, custom-fields

Having some trouble here... After setting up a simple ajax request, I can't seem to pass along a few custom field values.  It stems from a previous question I asked here: [How to display Wordpress Query using Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33510704/how-to-display-wordpress-query-using-ajax/).

So what I have is a chart with my Wordpress posts.  I am showing 25 posts using a template.  At the bottom of the page I have a button titled "load more."  When clicked I want it to load the next 25 posts using ajax so the page doesn't have to refresh.  This is what I have for the php template ajax request.

```
<?php require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-config.php'; ?>

<div id="load">
    <div id="first-item">
        <div id="tvvc-full">
           <ol>
             <?php
               $args = array( 
               'posts_per_page' => 25, 
               'offset'=> 0, 
               'category' => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'cats', true ), 
               'orderby' => meta_value_num,
               'meta_key' => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'custom_field_key', true ),
               'order' => 'DESC',
               'suppress_filters' => true,
               'date_query' => array(
               'after' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-176 hours')))
               );

$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>

<li>
    <ul>
       <?php $categories = get_the_category(); $separator = ' '; $output = '';
        if($categories){
            foreach($categories as $category) {
            $output .= '<a href="'.get_category_link( $category->term_id ).'" title="' . esc_attr( sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) ) . '">'.$category->cat_name.'</a>'.$separator;
            }
                echo trim($output, $separator)          ;
            }
            ?>
    </ul>
    <ul>
         <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, array( 300, 160) ); ?></a></ul><ul class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </ul>

<?php endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();?>

</ol>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

As of now, the meta fields aren't being grabbed from the template.  Is there any way to get the Post ID so that I can input it into the above php file?  Or better yet, get the meta data so that it populates the fields.  I know I can do it manually, but is there anyway to do it automatically?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your question is about the jQuery side of your code and not the PHP side (as it appears to be), you should edit your question to include only the generated html and javascript. None of us know what any of that PHP code will evaluate to so it makes it very difficult to try and help.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense.  I'm new at this.  Unfortunately, I don't feel like I can verbalize my problem very well.  However, I did find a workaround.  Thanks for your help.